# MySql Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1242

im having some problems to query at mysql a self many to many relationship
i got a Person table and a Friendship table

Person
pid | name | age
1 Jimmy 18
2 Lucas 25
3 Marie 12
4 Marie 40
5 John 30

Friendship
pid | pId2
1 3
2 3
4 1
5 3

---

So i need to check whats Marie's friends (correct answer: Lucas and John )

with the follow query i got the answer by the pid

```
SELECT p.name
FROM Person p
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL
    FROM Friendship f
    WHERE p.pid = f.pid
    AND (f.pid2 = 4 OR f.pid2 = 3))
OR EXISTS(SELECT NULL
    FROM Friendship f
    WHERE p.pid = f.pid2
    AND (f.pid = 4 OR f.pid = 3))
```

but what if i need to query by the name?the follow one doesnt work

```
SELECT p.name
FROM Person p
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL
    FROM Friendship f
    WHERE p.pid = f.pid
    AND f.pid2 = (SELECT pid FROM Person WHERE name = 'Marie'))
OR EXISTS(SELECT NULL
    FROM Friendship f
    WHERE p.pid = f.pid2
    AND f.pid = (SELECT pid FROM Person WHERE name = 'Marie'))
```

thanks for your help guys

Comment: Have you verified that `SELECT pid FROM Person WHERE name LIKE 'Marie%'` returns what you expect?

Comment: If this is homework; please tag it as so.

Comment: make some edits meanwhile sry

Answer (score 0):

I would do it through a JOIN.

```
SELECT fr.name FROM Person fr INNER JOIN Friendship ON(fr.pid = Friendship.pid2) INNER JOIN Person p ON(Friendship.pid = p.pid) WHERE p.name = 'Marie';
```

You could also do this through a JOIN and a subselect though.

```
SELECT name FROM Person INNER JOIN Friendship ON(Person.pid = Friendship.pid2) WHERE Friendship.pid IN (SELECT pid FROM Person WHERE name = 'Marie');
```

Comment: This ones doesnt work. make some edits on the question to make it more exactly. think the EXISTS query its more efficient but got the problem when check the relationship when i just search for the name

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What about the queries that I posted does not work?

Comment: yes. it doesnt match anything but you helped me anyway..a simply IN will solve me the prob..Just change before the Subquery the = with a IN on the 2 query i used. Thanks mate